# Stuck with bash not loaded after chmod -rwx mistake on /usr/

Tags: bash, debian, raspberry-pi, chmod

I am new to debian (on a Raspberry Pi), and it comes with mistakes...
Trying to give chmod permissions over the /usr/ files to my login (pi), I made a mistake, confusing "-" with "+". I executed the commande line :

```
$  sudo chmod -rwx /usr pi
```

wich gets me in a bad situation :
I cannot execute anythong anymore because bash won't load.
After reboot, and logged as pi, same issue with this errors :

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnuabihf/libcofi_rpi.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded: ignored
- bash: id: command not found
- bash: [: : integer expression expected
- bash: /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion: Permission denied
pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

and from there, my attemps to give chmod permissions to /usr/ are useless, because I don't have permissions at all...
most commands dont't work (startx, or else), as I get an error :

```
- bash: startx: command not found
```

How can I get out of that situation without restarting from scratch ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @Ashish `chmod 777` will break his system even more. My suggestion would be to remove your comment.

Comment: @Ashish, I agree with @tripleee;, `chmod -R 777 /usr` is  **horrible**  idea.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee for your contribution. It seems like you helped me getting in an even worse situation...

Comment: You should not be making changes directly in `/usr` anyway, you should let `dpkg` manage it for you.  If you want to install stuff locally, put it in `/usr/local` (which of course is technically inside `/usr` but still exempt from the "don't mess" rule).

Comment: Changing permissions using a livecd with knoppix or something seems like your only bet if your shell is completely shot and all your shells are in /usr. And like others said, never do chmod 777 recursively.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I actually found a [list with many username/password combinations](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions) for different distributions often used on Raspberry. So check first, if your distribution is in there (I guess either Debian or Raspbian) and try the passwords there at the login prompt. If they do not work on SSH, try them directly (root login via SSH could be disabled).

### Old entry

The Debian distribution for raspberry does not seem to have a password for root set by default. Thus, you cannot login as root. I guess, due to the access changes you cannot execute `sudo`?

So, the whole problem has to be solved from another operating system: Insert the SD card into another PC. If you do not have linux, you can boot it with a live CD like Ubuntu or Knoppix.

From there you can `mount` the SD card:

```
mount /dev/sdX? /mnt
sudo chmod 0755 /mnt/usr
```

Here `X` is variable and you have to find it out. Best is, you insert the SD card after the whole system has booted. Then the SD card should have the highest letter (e.g. d, if you have three other harddisks in your PC). The question mark `?` has to be replaced with a number (probably `1`).

Comment: Thanks @Aufziehvogel. You are right, sudo doeśnt wok. I.ll try your solution! Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your update @Aufziehvogel. Your link is interesting. Unfortunatly, I am in a Debian distribution, and already using default username:password (pi:raspberry)... this same user I disabled permission for by mistake. Raspberry is a prototype plateform, fortunately for me I had very few personal files. I am considering starting my installation back from scratch. It will teach me a lesson. And I'll have to write some Python again... thoses are the joys of being a nood programmer ! ;) I can't blame anyone but me. And I feel gratefuul for all the support I had here !

Answer (score 0):

You will have to log in as `root`. so that you can ignore the permissions you have set, and then run:

```
chmod 0755 /usr
```

Comment: thanks @DopeGhoti . Do you know what the default password would be for root ?

Comment: As much as I could find out quickly, neither the Raspberry distribution of Debian nor Raspian have a default root password. Guess you're then stuck there, because you cannot access neither `su` nor `sudo`?

Comment: Correction: According to another [list at eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions), the password is either `hexxeh` or `raspbian`.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel, the problem was that with `/usr` set to chmod `-rwx`, no one other than root can run any of the binaries in e. g. `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`.  On my installation, the path to `sudo` is `/usr/bin/sudo`.